# Do not clear form content upon POST

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-form

I am using a Spring form with tabs, each tab again has a form.
The problems are

1)After the form submission, the error messages are displayed but the form content is cleared which should not happen
2)After the form submission the control immediately goes to the default tab which is the first tab in my case. I want the control to stay on current tab after transaction and not go to default tab.

This is the first time I am working using Spring MVC, JSP, jQuery. Please let me know if I have to make any changes.

administrator.jsp

[image]

Below is the code for Manage Users tab functionality.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btnManage').click(function() {
            if($.trim($('#userId').val()) == ''){
                $('#area5').html("User Id is a required field.");
             }else if($.trim($('#region').val()) == 'NONE'){
                $('#area5').html("Region is a required field.");
             }else{
            $('#manageUserForm').submit();
             }
        });
$('#btnCancel5').click(function(e) {
            $('#manageUserForm').trigger("reset");
            $('#area5').html("");
        });
});
```

administrator.jsp:

```
<div id="tab5" class="tab">
        <div class="devices" >
        <form:form method="post" id="manageUserForm" modelAttribute="adminUser" action="/DeviceManager/admin/manageUser">
        <div align=center class="message" id="area5">${serverError5}</div> 
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">User Id:</div> 
            <div class="plinput"><form:input path="userId" type="text" size="29"/></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">Region:</div> 
            <div class="plselect">
            <form:select path="region">
            <form:option value="NONE" label="------- Select One -------" />
            <form:option value="A" label="A"/>
            <form:options items="${regionList}"/>
            </form:select>
        </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>
        <div>
            <div class="plLabelSearch">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="plinput"><a id="btnManage" class="abutton">OK</a></div>
            <div class="plinput"><a id="btnCancel5" class="abutton">Cancel</a></div>
        </div>
    </form:form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: clear the `${serverError5}` variable

Comment: Thank you. where should i clear it and which of the 2 problems would it solve ?

Comment: when form is submitted it will be reload and the form will be empty dont submit form so it wont empty

Comment: I got the tab issue working - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37493269/6046654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-render the page with the data from the original form submission.

In your case this probably means your form should contain a few hidden fields to allow you to determine which tab you are on, your JSP will need to be able to understand this data and use it to select the appropriate tab.

Answer (score -2):

because you submission is not asynchronous,after you submit,the administrator.jsp is reset,so the error message is display ,owing to this code `<div align=center class="message" id="area5">${serverError5}</div>`