# Form submit should stay on the same tab

Tags: jquery, html

On submitting the form by clicking a button, upon page reload same tab should be opened, but it is going to default tab. I have tried **local storage** but it doesn't work. What is wrong with my code?

[This is working now. See my answer below]

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('show.bs.tab', function(e) {
           localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
           });
           var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
           if(activeTab){
           $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
           }
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            // Show/Hide Tabs
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);
            // Change/remove current tab to active
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');       
            e.preventDefault();
            });
$('#btnLock').click(function() {
            $('#lockForm').submit();
            });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs" align="center">
  <ul class="tab-links">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-1">Register</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-2">Lock</a></li>
  </ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tabs-1" class="tab active">
        <form:form....> <div class="plinput"><a id="btnRegister" class="abutton">Register</a></div> 
        </form:form>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2" class="tab">
        <form:form...> <div class="plinput"><a id="btnLock" class="abutton">Lock</a></div>
        </form:form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: debug here: `if(activeTab){
           $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
           }` is activeTab defined, and does it contain what you expect.

Comment: first does your browser support localStorage and sessionStorage?  
second, this should be controlled in your action code server, are you using php or java or another language?, you should code in the server side a variable and pass it to your html

Comment: From the code you've given us, it has to be the `localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));`. What is the `show.bs.tab` event?

Comment: Kevin, You are right. I also realised that setting the current tab to a variable is being done twice in my program. Changed the jQuery and it is working fine now. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things to fix.  `.tab('show')` should be `.show('tab')`

I changed the `show.bs.tab` to `click`.

I made both divs `display:none` to start.

And finally, I put an onload function to show the div that should be shown.

```
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('click', function (e) {
        localStorage.setItem('activeTab', $(e.target).attr('href'));
      });

      var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');

      if (activeTab) {
        $('#myTab a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').show('tab');
      }

      $('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function (e) {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        // Show/Hide Tabs
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);
        // Change/remove current tab to active
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        e.preventDefault();
      });
      $('#btnLock').click(function () {
        $('#lockForm').submit();
      });
      $(window).on('load',function () {
        $(localStorage.getItem('activeTab')).show();
      });
    });

  </script>
  <div class="tabs" align="center">
    <ul class="tab-links">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-1">Register</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tabs-2">Lock</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tabs-1" class="tab active" style="border: 1px solid blue;display:none;">
        <form:form>
          <div class="plinput"><a id="btnRegister" class="abutton">Register</a></div>
        </form:form>
      </div>
      <div id="tabs-2" class="tab" style="border: 1px solid red;display:none;">
        <form:form>
          <div class="plinput"><a id="btnLock" class="abutton">Lock</a></div>
        </form:form>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
<a href="../login.aspx">Somewhere Else</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

This got me working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       var activeTab = localStorage.getItem('activeTab');
       if(activeTab){
       $('.tab-links a[href="' + activeTab + '"]').tab('show');
       }
$('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
            var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            localStorage.setItem('activeTab', currentAttrValue);
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
            jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);  
            jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');       
            e.preventDefault();
            });
});
```