# Staying in same tab on form submit but show new content(django)

Tags: django

I have three tabs. The first tab is set as the default tab. In the second tab, there is a form button. How do I make it so that when you click on the form button it calls a function in view, and that function in view renders NEW content in the SAME tab. Something like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37492345/form-submit-should-stay-on-the-same-tab) i would imagine

So far I have something like this:

```
<div class="tab">
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')"     
id="defaultOpen">London</button>
<button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,      
'Paris')">Paris</button>
 <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event,       
 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</button>
 </div>

<div id="London" class='progress-wrapper'>
<div id='progress-bar' class='progress-bar' style="background-color:    
#68a9ef$
</div>
<div id="progress-bar-message">Waiting for progress to start...</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"    
class="topright">&times</span>
<h3>Paris</h3>
<p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
<span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'"     
class="topright">&times</span>
 <h3>Tokyo</h3>
 <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: What's your attempts?

Comment: I have no idea where to start. At the moment I have an idea of how to stay on the same tab via localstorage. But i have no idea how to rewrite the content of the SAME tab.